# The most efficient way to count documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to count the number of documents recorded filtering by a range of dates and IDs. The command I used is shown next:

```
db.collection.aggregate([   
                   {$match:{$and:[{Date: {$gte: ISODate("2014-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2014-06-01T00:00:00.000Z")}},
                                  {Id:{$gte:1000, $lt:5000}}]} },
                   {$group:{ _id:{ID:"$Id"},NMESG:{$sum:1}}}],
                   {allowDiskUse: true})
```

The collection has 370 million documents and the execution time is at least more than 24h... because it does not return any results. I tested the code with a subset with no problems. Date and Id are indexed as a single field indexs and as a compound index. The MongoDB server is configured as a replica set.

EDIT: The compound key has beed created with the fields  Id and Date in this order. (Id,Date)

Is there a more efficient way to perform this task?

Comment: Why aggregation? Are the `Id` fields here not unique? Is your "compound" index actually in the same order you are issuing to query?

Comment: The `$and` seems to be unnecessary. When your `$match`-object has multiple keys, they all have to be fulfilled anyway. It *might* be possible that the `$and` confuses the index use. I don't think this is likely, but it might be possible.

Comment: @NeilLunn It is not unique. Several documents with unique `_id` may have the same `Id`. @Philipp how can I concatenate multiple keys in `$match`?

Comment: @Emer the `$and` even though unnecessary does not "confuse" the query. If indeed you need to "group" the "Id" values together then you still need to aggregate. But you still have not answered the second question I asked. Please edit your question with the details rather than post them in comments.